# How to approach finding where in .net API code a request to an API endpoint is processed?

Tags: asp.net, .net, api, react-native, networking

I'm writing a React Native app that uses a .Net API. I'm trying to troubleshoot some things in the API code, but have never used .Net before. For example, I have the API running on `localhost:5000` and am trying to hit the `api/token` endpoint. I've found an instance of `api/token` in the API code, but it's tricky to trace it back and try to find the actual entry point to the API. Basically I want to add breakpoints in the API code so that I can step through the code when I hit an endpoint from my app.

Can anyone advise me on how to approach this?

Comment: Are you simply looking for the code for the api/token endpoint? The endpoints are usually located in the **Controllers** folder.

Comment: @HashedPassword I actually have an updated question from this here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60035057/react-native-why-does-appending-query-parameters-to-my-net-api-calls-automatic