# React Native: Why does appending query parameters to my .Net API calls automatically return a 404 error?

Tags: asp.net, .net, reactjs, api, react-native

In my React Native app, I'm trying to hit an endpoint in an API written in .Net. I've got the API code on my local machine, so I'm trying to hit it with a call to `fetch(127.0.0.1:5000/api/token)`. This returns a 404 error. If I instead hit `fetch(127.0.0.1:5000/)`, it returns successfully. The API code hit in this case is `HomeController.cs`, which contains this:

```
namespace InTowAPI2.Controllers
{
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [Route("/a")]
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        // GET api/values
        [HttpGet]
        public string Get()
        {
            return "Ok";
        }
    }
}
```

When I make the call to `fetch(127.0.0.1:5000/)`, it returns "Ok" and hits the breakpoint I set in `HomeController.cs`. The other file `ValuesController.cs` that should be hit when I call `fetch(127.0.0.1:5000/api/token)` contains this code (plus more after it):

```
namespace InTowAPI2.Controllers
{
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [Route("/api/[controller]")]
    ...
    ...
```

When I call `fetch(127.0.0.1:5000/api/token)`, the breakpoint in `ValuesController.cs` is not hit, and it returns a 404 error.

What I tried to do to troubleshoot this was, since `HomeController.cs` was working, I replaced `[Route("/")]` with `[Route("/api")]`, and made a call to `fetch(127.0.0.1:5000/api)`. This also returned a 404 error.

**What I Want To Know:**

Why is it that hitting the API code containing `[Route("/")]` with `fetch(127.0.0.1:5000/)` works, but modifying it to hit `[Route("/api")]` with `fetch(127.0.0.1:5000/api)` throws a 404 error?

Comment: Hello gkeenley! Did you try to make curl calls from the terminal in order to test the endpoints and discard the API being the reason for the issue?

Comment: Hi mantingablue! Nope, I've never used Curl. What do you suggest?

Comment: are you using linux? what's your OS? Fist thing I'd do is curl at your console/terminal to  check if curl is installed. 
Maybe this can help you doing the calls once curl is installed: https://www.baeldung.com/curl-rest

Comment: Before I dig into that, I'm using a Mac and I tested it with Postman. Is it worth trying to do it with Curl too?

Comment: ohk... If you already tested with Postman and it worked fine, no need!  Sorry I didnt think to ask, I need to think a bit more out of the terminal :-)

Comment: No no, it didn't work fine haha, it gave the same 404

Comment: Then curl may help :-) It always works for me. If I dont get the expected result from the terminal doing a clean post/get/put/etc call, then I check the api. Else, I focus in my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is the routing.

```
[Route("/api/[controller]")]
```

This RouteAttribute definition will route the endpoint to the name of the controller.

> The other file ValuesController.cs that should be hit...

Seems like you controller name is **ValuesController**, which would create an endpoint on **/api/values**, not **/api/token**.

To fix this, do one of the following things:

1. Change the name of the controller from ValuesController to TokenController.
2. Change the RouteAttribute from [Route("/api/[controller]")] to [Route("/api/token")].